# How do I update/redraw a GTK Widget (GTKLabel) internally without a key press event using python?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have some code below that is attempting to update a GTK Label element.  I'm including two files:  the ui file and the py file.

UI file:

```
<glade-interface>
  <widget class="GtkWindow" id="ApplicationFrame">
    <property name="width_request">320</property>
    <property name="height_request">240</property>
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="events">GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Simple</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center-always</property>
    <property name="default_width">320</property>
    <property name="default_height">240</property>
    <property name="decorated">False</property>
    <property name="gravity">center</property>
    <child>
      <widget class="GtkFixed" id="layout">
        <property name="width_request">320</property>
        <property name="height_request">240</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <child>
          <widget class="GtkLabel" id="l1">
            <property name="width_request">320</property>
            <property name="height_request">40</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="xalign">0</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">l1</property>
          </widget>
          <packing>
            <property name="y">43</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </widget>
    </child>
  </widget>
</glade-interface>
```

Python File

```
import os
from time import sleep as wait
import gtk as gtk
import gtk.glade as glade
import gobject

class Application(object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.glade = glade.XML("simple.ui")
        self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui (self):
        self.window = self.glade.get_widget("ApplicationFrame")
        self.l1 = self.glade.get_widget("l1")
        self.names = {'l1' : self.l1}
        self.all = [self.l1]
        gobject.timeout_add(1000,self.display_me)
        gobject.timeout_add(100,self.do_something_that_takes_a_while)
        self.window.add_events(gtk.gdk.KEY_PRESS_MASK)
        self.window.connect("key-press-event", self.handler)
        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)
        self.window.show()

    def get_signal (self,widget,event):
        keyname = gtk.gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
        ctrl = event.state & gtk.gdk.CONTROL_MASK
        alt = event.state & gtk.gdk.MOD1_MASK
        shift = event.state & gtk.gdk.SHIFT_MASK
        name = []
        if ctrl and keyname not in ["Control_L","Control_R"]: 
            name.append("CTRL")
        if alt and keyname not in ["Alt_L","Alt_R"]:
            name.append("ALT")
        if shift and keyname not in ["Shift_L","Shift_R"]:
            name.append("SHIFT")
        name.append(keyname)
        name = "+".join(name)
        return name

    def handler (self,widget,event):
        name = self.get_signal(widget,event)
        if name.lower() in ['ctrl+x','ctrl+c','alt+q']:
            self.destroy()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

    def delete_event (self,widget=None,event=None,data=None):
        return False

    def destroy (self,widget=None,data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def get (self,item):
        if isinstance(item, str): 
            if item in self.names:
                item = self.names[item]
        retval = None
        if hasattr(item,"text"):
            retval = item.text()
        elif hasattr(item,"get_label"):
            retval = item.get_label()
        return retval

    def set (self,item,text='',font=None):
        print 'Setting...'
        if isinstance(item, str): 
            if item in self.names:
                item = self.names[item]
        retval = None
        if font == None and hasattr(self,"page") and hasattr(self.page,"NORMAL_FONT"): 
                font = self.page.NORMAL_FONT
        if hasattr(item,"setText"):
            retval = item.setText(text)
        elif font == None:
            if hasattr(item,'set_text'):
                retval = item.set_text(text)
        elif hasattr(item,"set_label"):
            retval = item.set_label(text)
            if hasattr(item,"modify_font") and font != None:
                item.modify_font(font)
        item.queue_draw()
        self.try_to_update(item)
        print 'done'
        return retval

    def try_to_update (self,item):
        """
        do something here to update the visual screen????
        """
        print str(self)

    def do_something_that_takes_a_while (self):
        timeout = 15
        while timeout != 0:
            self.set('l1','%s' % timeout)
            wait(1)
            timeout -= 1
            print timeout
        return 1

    def clean (self):
        if item != None:
            self.set(item,empty_text)
        else:
            if hasattr(self,'all'):
                for item in self.all:
                    self.set(item)

    def display_me (self):
        print str(self)
        return True

    def __str__ (self):
        space = 25
        value = '%'+str(space)+'s'
        lines = ['\n','-'*79]
        if hasattr(self,'all'):
            line = []
            for obj in self.all:
                obj_value = self.get(obj)
                line.append(value % obj_value if obj_value != None else '')
                #line.append(value % ' ')
            lines.append(''.join(line))
        lines.append('-'*79)
        return '\n'.join(lines)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from time import sleep as wait
    SEC = 1
    app = Application()
    app.main()
```

This should be simple, but I'm completely missing what I'm doing wrong.  The element, l1, is not getting updated properly.  I think the code within try_to_update is where I need to update the UI, but I'm at a loss as to which function I need to call.  Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a style recommendation: `type(item) == type('')` => `type(item) == str` => `isinstance(item, str)`

Comment: I've never used multiprocessing, but it looks like a `SimpleFrame` object is being shared without following the mechanism described in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Comment: Understood.  I don't actually think that multiprocessing is the issue.  I was using that to identify a process that is similar to what I'm doing: something is updating the display independent of a GTK event...but the GUI itself is not actually updating.

Comment: Sorry to insist, maybe I'm mssing something, but an object is being updated in a process in which no gtk mainloop is running and the new value is expected to be propagated to a remote process running a different python interpreter and generate an event that updates the display. Looking at the documentation I don't see that this kind of interaction is supported without explicitly creating a proxy for that object.

Comment: All right.  I've updated the code to remove the confusion with the processing.  In this case, I'm calling a "long process" with a timer and the display is not updating.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to use the Widget's [`queue_draw`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--queue-draw) function:

> *The queue_draw_area() method invalidates the rectangular area of the widget (...) by calling the* `gtk.gdk.Window.invalidate_rect()` *method on the widget's window and all its child windows.*

But, as you are already doing that in your `set` method, my guess is that the

```
if hasattr(item,'show')
```

check prevents the item from updating. Another check is to call the `queue_draw` function on the entire window, and see if that updates things.

Alternatively, force the events that are queued to be processed as follows:

```
while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration_do(True)
```

Comment: That's on line 83.  :(  Didn't work.  Also, item does have the attribute 'show' so that should execute... I originally had item.show there.  But I changed it because I had read the same functionality you did in the documentation.  I've removed the if statement for clarity.

Comment: Ok. Try to call `while gtk.events_pending(): gtk.main_iteration_do(True)` in your update function; perhaps the event queue isn't processed when you expect it.

Comment: Thank you. That worked wonderfully. I have a function now that calls `gtk_main_iteration_do()` after `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` in C.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that happens in the code is that while `do_something_that_takes_a_while` is executed, no events are being processed. One way to solve that is to force event processing at some point inside that method:

```
--- code.py 2011-12-05 10:32:53.000000000 +0100
+++ code.py.bak 2011-12-05 10:27:22.000000000 +0100
@@ -95,8 +95,6 @@
         timeout = 15
         while timeout != 0:
             self.set('l1','%s' % timeout)
-            while gtk.events_pending():
-                gtk.main_iteration()
             wait(1)
             timeout -= 1
             print timeout
```